# Working with functionals

Tags: functions, function-construction, pure-function

I am trying to work with functionals in Mathematica, this means that I want to define a function of a function. I defined my function of a function as:

```
energyFunctional[ψ_] := 
Integrate[1/2 (D[ψ[x], x])^2 + 1/2*x^2*(ψ[x])^2, {x, -∞,∞}];
```

This works really good when I just want to fill in a simple function defined as for example:

```
ψ=(1/π)^(1/4) Exp[-(#^2/2)]&
```

But as soon as I try to add a parameter to vary my function it all fails, given that I define:

```
ψ[b_] := (b/π)^(1/4) Exp[-((b*#^2)/2)] &
```

and try to do

```
energyFunctional[ψ[1]]
```

I get no results at all.

Comment: Typo? the function names are not identical, I do get result `energyfunctionaal[ψ[1]]-> 1/2`.

Comment: FWIW; it's atypical to pass around anonymous functions. Just pass around expressions instead (i.e. omit the & at the end).

Comment: Two typos, in fact: `functionaal` and `Functional` (lowercase and doubled "a").

Comment: @rhermans Sorry acknowledged the typo in the comment to halirutan's answer. But my question is answered!

Comment: @rhermans no problem at all ;-). I should have posted the aknowlegement also as a comment to my question.

Comment: @Pickett If i were to pass it around as an expression, won't this get me into trouble at some point? If I for example write it as an expression in "x", but "x" has an assigned value ?

Comment: @Dominique Well yes, but it shouldn't cause a problem if everything is done properly with scoping constructs in the appropriate places and so on.

Comment: @Pickett true that :). I'll give passing expressions around a try! Only using Mathematica for 4 years now on a fairy basic level. It's only until a few months that I am going to more high-level stuff. So if you have any more tips, please feel welcome to share :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct the typo in your code. I'm not even sure how this can happen, when you copied the example from your notebook.

Additionally, you shouldn't use $\psi$ for both, a function and a variable. Once this is fixed:

```
energyFunctional[ψ_] := 
  Integrate[
   1/2 (D[ψ[x], x])^2 + 
    1/2*x^2*(ψ[x])^2, {x, -∞, ∞}];

ψ1 = (1/π)^(1/4) Exp[-(#^2/2)] &
ψ2[b_] := (b/π)^(1/4) Exp[-((b*#^2)/2)] &
```

you get

```
energyFunctional[ψ1]
(* 1/2 *)

energyFunctional[ψ2[1]]
(* 1/2 *)
```

Comment: The typo was because of the fact that I was simultaneously copying and translating, my bad. And this was indeed the solution that I tried, and it still didn't work. But closing and reopening the kernel cured it :)